# Talkback not reading aria-label

Tags: android, wai-aria, talkback

I am using Cordova to make an Android hybrid app. I am using Android 5.1 on a Galaxy S6.

It seems that Talkback is not reading the `aria-label` to notify the user when the menu is opened or closed. Does anyone know if this a known issue with Android?

Comment: I can't answer your question and don't know Cordova. But in HTML there is [area-expanded to indicate the state of a collapsible element](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-expanded_to_indicate_the_state_of_a_collapsible_element) maybe this also works in your setting

Comment: Thanks, that works